# HFSM StateForge - high cpu iowait and asynchronous processing

Tags: c++, boost, fsm

I have an application which implements a state machine based on StateForge (StateBuilderCpp) generator. A state machine is defined as asynchronous and uses boost in the generated code:

`<settings asynchronous="true" library="boost">`

Actions (implemented methods) are very fast but are called frequently - events are triggered with 10ms intervals. State machine uses boost ioservice.

I run the application on a single core atom processor. Generally that pc is strongly utilized by others applications and I have noticed that sometimes when a cpu has a high iowait a dozen or so events are queued. Is it coincidence ? How to explains such behaviour ?